# Mysql data recovery using mysqlbinlog

Tags: mysql, binary-log, mysqlbinlog

I accidentally dropped a schema without backing it up.

And now I want to use ***mysqlbinlog*** utility to perform recovery. (It seems that mysqlbinlog is a good tool). And it needs those binary log files to perform recovery.

Now I have the following confusions:

1. I ***can not*** find those binary log files. So where are they located?
2. If the operations are not logged or binary logging is not enabled, how to enable it.
   I have read the mysql documentation, it says they are enabled ***as default***. But I cannot find those files,though...
3. Is it possible to recover the data and schema through the ***/var/log/mysqld.log*** file

Comment: Have you tried looking for `~/.mysql_history`?  It could help recover the operations done from just the command line.  If you had done anything that could reveal the schema, it should be in there.

Comment: Pity, I used phpmyadmin so those operations are not through commandline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the line `log = /path/to/mysql.log` uncommented in `my.cnf`, the queries will be in the `mysql.log`.  That is, answering the third question.